# What are some examples of three-mora atamadaka verbs besides 帰る?

Tags: verbs, pitch-accent

I couldn't find a good way to research this on my own, I'm afraid.
I'm not looking for a comprehensive list by any means (in before it turns out 帰る is the only one...), but rather just a few examples because 帰る always seemed pretty special to me in regard to its pitch accent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are extremely rare.  Besides 「帰{かえ}る」, I could only think of the following in Standard Japanese.

- 「入{はい}る」
- 「通{とお}る」
- 「返{かえ}す」
- 「参{まい}る」

*** In case anyone is unsure of what the questioner is talking about, s/he is looking for three-mora verbs in which the pitch accent pattern is 「[〇〇〇]{HLL}」.

「頭高{あたまだか}」 means "head-high".

Comment: What about `返る`? No way `帰る` and `返す` are both 頭高 but not `返る`, right? ...right?

Comment: BTW, do you have a good reference for searching the pitch accent of words? In English preferably, but Japanese is fine too :)

Comment: @Rightleg 返る is arguably the same word as 帰る.  It's just a spelling difference to capture a different nuance. Like if we had a different spelling for "run" (a business) versus "run" (a race).

Comment: @Right, http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/search/index/sortprefix:accent/narabi1:kata_asc/narabi2:accent_asc/narabi3:mola_asc/yure:visible/curve:invisible/details:invisible/limit:20/word:%E6%87%90%E4%B8%AD%E9%9B%BB%E7%81%AF とか　https://accent.u-biq.org/a.html　とか、あと　https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%87%90%E4%B8%AD%E9%9B%BB%E7%81%AF　☜「かいちゅうでんとう **［5］** 」☜ 数字で表示されます

Comment: 申す should be in this list, too.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.wadoku.de/ has accent patterns for quite a lot of entries; it translates to German, though…

But its data can be downloaded in XML format, a comprehensive list could be compiled from that with a bit of programming skills.

Comment: @ajsmart It's Japanese - German dictionary, which includes pitch accent for Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [OJAD, the Online Japanese Accent Dictionary](http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/), to be particularly useful in providing pitch patterns for conjugated forms as well.  And poking around just now, I discovered that the site does have tools for looking up, say, 1) all verbs 2) that have 頭高 pitch patterns and 3) have 3 morae.

Search results: http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/search/index/category:verb/accent_type:2/mola:3/sortprefix:accent/narabi1:kata_asc/narabi2:accent_asc/narabi3:mola_asc/yure:visible/curve:invisible/details:invisible/limit:20

If that list is accurate, there are 10 such 3-mora verbs with 頭高 pitch patterns.

If you're curious about other sets of common terms with a specific pitch pattern and length, just play around with the 検索の条件 options.  Happy searching!

PS: The UI of the site is all in Japanese by default, but you can click the flag icons in the upper right to choose a different UI language.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was posted 4 years ago but I'll offer my insight anyhow. I too am on a "pitch learning" journey with my Japanese vocabulary, and one interesting rule I've found is that most katakana 3 mora loan words are atamadaka.

テレビ - TErebi
カメラ - KAmera
バナナ - BAnana
ドバイ - DObai
ハワイ - HAwai
アイス - Aisu

This rule is actually part of another rule that states most loan katakana words have a high to low pitch on the *3rd* to last mora.

I hope whoever comes across this reply finds it useful.